# Broadcom 4312 not working with 22.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 22.04, broadcom

Dell Laptop E5500 wireless not working.
I had previously installed 18.06 and the wireless worked.  Installed 22.04 and the wireless does not work.  I have tried following other instructions on how to get it working but somewhere along the line something does not work or the output in terminal does not show what should be what is shown on line.  lshw -c network shows this: [screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEPlG.png)
it shows the broadcom wireless card and shows the driver as driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0
When I tried sudo ifconfig wlan0 up;iwconfig;  I got this output: [screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhbgm.png)  So I wonder if the driver is properly installed.
I am not sure what to do now.

Comment: Install `firmware-b43-installer`

Comment: How?  Where do I download it and then how is it installed?

Comment: I gave you a link with a thorough manual.

Comment: Screenshots of text are much harder to read than text, so please copy & paste text & not screenshots.  Check your details; Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format, so 22.04 refers to the 2022-April release of Ubuntu (*2000 is added to the year*) and the only ever release in June was back in 2006 (ie. Ubuntu 6.06) so there was no Ubuntu 18.06.

Comment: @guiverc Hi, sorry it should have been 18.04.6.  I tried the copy and paste but it did not keep the format, was just one long line of text with no spacing.  I couldn't get it to keep the format so I just posted the screen shot.

Comment: @Pilot6 sorry I don't see a link anywhere in your comment.

Comment: The link is above the question.

Comment: followed the link, tried what was suggested, didn't work, tried a few other things that were suggested and ended up with an OS that would not boot.  Just wiped the hard drive.